# Numerical value of keyframe in the Graph Editor

Tags: keyframes

I'm manipulating animation keyframes in the Graph Editor in Blender and although my keys are clearly marked "Value", I can't see exactly what the value of this key is ; I can only eyeball its location by manually moving the keyframe up and down the Y axis in on the graph.

I would like to manually set the height of the keyframe in the Graph Editor by inputting a numeric value. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the keyframe in the graph editor.

Press <kbd>N</kbd> to open the properties panel. Go to the **F-Curve** tab and the *Active Keyframe* section. You can read and write the keyframes *Frame* and *Value*.

[image: keyframe value]

Answer (score 5):

[**Show Sliders**](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/channels.html#sliders)

From the graph editor view menu toggle [view sliders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/graph_editor/channels.html#sliders)

[image]

Now each fcurve has a slider in the channels region.

[image]

When the scene frame is on a keyframe, highlighted yellow, updating will change the keyframe value. When green, will add a new keyframe at that frame.